# error not found: type > and type mismatch play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

The following code involves an http request in the play framework. I am including the errors in the code...

```
def requestWebservice(drug: String) : String = {
    val drugEntry = "search" -> drug
    var a = 100
    val request = ws.url(apiUrl).withQueryString(apiKey, drugEntry, 
    apiLimit, apiSkip).get()
    val jsonresults = Await.result(request, 10 seconds).json
    val countEntries: Int = (jsonresults \ "meta" \ "results" \ 
    "total").as[Int]
    //error "not found: type >"

    while (countEntries: Int > a) {
    // type mismatch; found : Unit, required: String (countEntries)
        skip = skip + 100;
        request;
        jsonresults;
        a = a + 100;

    }   
}
```

I am new to scala and the play framework and I have a problem probably trivial for someone with some experience. I am doing an http request to a web server that returns 100 results at a time. I have tried to point to a number that gives the total of the results so that I can repeat the request with a while loop if the total is more than 100. The structure of the jsonresults is the following

```
"meta": {
    "disclaimer": "",
    "terms": "",
    "license": "",
    "last_updated": "",
"results": {
    "skip": 0,
    "limit": 100,
    "total": 1742
}
```

I know that Unit means that nothing comes back and that probably I am not pointing to the right field correctly, but how else could I point to the total? And why do I get the first error, where scala doesn't recognise the operator ">"? I would be grateful for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `: Int` in the while, as the type of `countEntries` is automatically inferred - this means the compiler automatically figures out that the type of `countEntries` is an `Int`:

```scala
while (countEntries > a) {
  ...
}
```

Also, if you want to check the official `while` specification in Scala, it's [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#while-loop-expressions). You can keep the type specification if you want, just make sure you wrap it between braces:

```scala
while ((countEntries: Int) > a) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. Silly me, it worked fine.

Comment: No worries, enjoy :) I recommend going through some Scala tutorials before you start using other libs (such as play) to get used with the language

Comment: Will do. Thanks.